# Django - updating primary key charfield duplicates instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with a charfield serving as primary key.
While creating an instance (through admin panel) everything is fine and my clean method works ok too. But if I come back to update myfield than not only clean method fails to catch non-numeric characters, but the whole instance is duplicated. One with old myfield value and the new one with altered myfield.

```
# models.py
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if not re.match(r'[0-9]+', self.pesel):
            raise ValidationError('Digits only.', code='invalid')
        super(Mymodel, self).clean()
```

How can I fix this? I need it to be a primary key and I need it to be editable. And extra issue with this clean not functioning well, I think it may be connected. I'm Django 1.5.5

Comment: Why do you need it to be the be the pk? Why not have an automatic id, as is the default?

Comment: not my call, project requirement

Comment: Why don't you put the validation into a `ModelForm`?

Comment: I meant updating an instance through django admin. Changing the value of myfield and clicking save button doesn't change the actual instance but create (duplicating all the other fields) the new one.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Answer (score 7):

> I meant updating an instance through django admin. Changing the value
>   of myfield and clicking save button doesn't change the actual instance
>   but create (duplicating all the other fields) the new one.

This is how django works, from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert):

- If the object’s primary key attribute is set to a value that evaluates to `True` (i.e., a value other than `None` or the empty string), Django executes an `UPDATE`.
- If the object’s primary key attribute is not set or if the `UPDATE` didn’t update anything, Django executes an `INSERT`.

You are getting caught in the second clause. The first time django attempts to do an update, your new primary key value doesn't exist; so django will insert a new record.

Do you need to have it as a *primary key* or just as a *key*? Typically a primary key is a unique value; once a record is created (and since you have foreign keys, linked) - you do not modify the primary key otherwise your relationships will break. In fact, most databases will raise an error if you try to do this; as you will have records pointing to a key that doesn't exist.

Comment: OK then. How can I keep myfield as a pk but prevent editing? If I set readonly_fields = ('myfield',) on the ModelAdmin it is readonly during instance creation too. It makes no sense of course.

Comment: The best suggestion I have for you is to use the built-in primary key as the actual primary key, and use `myfield` as a separate value. Otherwise it is on you to ensure that the primary key is unique and enforce all integrity rules yourself. Asking for the primary key to be editable by the user is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to make it creatable but non-editable by the user?

Comment: It depends if you want the user to enter a value for it or not.

Comment: Yes, user enters value during instance creation.